# Making items draggable

Tags: iphone

How are objects made draggable on iphone?

How is an item/object moved by the user. e.g. apps can be moved on the homescreen and they icons follow the users finger.

How can e.g. a tableview cell contents be moved if the user holds down on it and then moves their finger?

What controls the movement of these objects to follow a users finger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in support of dragging controls and you need to implement one. My answer to another question is related and might help.

[Dragging values onto labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189544/dragging-values-onto-labels/5189698#5189698)